# Trouble Calling Function

Tags: c#

I can't call function I've tried `Fibonacci(uint k []);`, `Fibonacci(k);` etc. but nothing works

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace fibonaciv
{
    class Program
    {
        uint[] k;
        public static void Fibonacci(uint[] t)
         {
            uint n = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 93; i++)
            {
                n++;
                 if (n <= 2)
               {
                    t[i] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    uint a = 1;
                    uint b = 1;
                    uint c = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < n - 2; j++)
                    {
                        c = a + b;
                        a = b;
                        b = c;
                    }
                    t[i] = c;
                }
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           // uint[] k;
            Fibonacci(k []);// how call the funcion
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You don't specify the type of a variable when you're calling a function with it, only when you're defining the function. So, just Fibonacci(k) *should* work. Rather, it will if you also actually assign a value to k. What error are you getting when you call it that way? (I don't suppose it's "use of unassigned local variable 'k'"?) edit: nope, Jonathan caught it, the actual issue was that you were defining the variable in your class, and not as a static.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an instance of an array to this function:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    // Create a new array, assign a reference to it to the k variable.
    uint[] k = new uint[94];

    // Call the function, passing in the array reference.
    Fibonacci(k);
}
```

You don't need `uint[] k` at the class level to do this, but you do need to make sure that the array variable actually holds a reference to an array, or you are going to get a runtime exception when you try to use it.  (`new uint[94]` allocates and returns a reference to a new array of 94 `uint` values.)

I would also suggest changing this line to account for any size array that might be passed in.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 93; i++)
// Change to this:
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, to pass a variable that's an array as an argument to your function, just use the variable's name, without the array item accessor `[]`. Change `Fibonacci(k []);` to `Fibonacci(k);`.

Second, k is an instance member, so you can't access it from a static context (i.e. your static Main method). A quick fix would be to just declare k as static. Change `uint[] k;` to `static uint[] k;`.

Edit: now that it gets past the point of compiling, it still needs a quick change to make it work.

Initialize your `k` array so it can hold the values that you will set in your Fibonacci method. Change `uint[] k` to `uint[] k = new uint[94]`.

Comment: Don't forget to initialize `k` to an array instance, otherwise you're just passing `null` to the function.

Comment: Good catch, I assumed he had just commented out the variable because he was confused. I hadn't noticed he was trying to call a static method with a variable that he'd defined in his class.

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. Wanted to get my foot in the door with the obvious errors.